# Why is there a huge performance gap using Map with more than 100 List entries

Tags: list-manipulation, map

im using Map on a List like this:

```
cube= {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 4}, ... , {5, 5, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}
```

Mapping the whole List with 125 entries takes like 2.5s.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Map[Apply[d[[#1, #2, #3]] &, #] &, cube];
 ]

{2.552146, Null}
```

Mapping in two sublists with less than 100 entries the whole thing takes nearly no time.

```
 AbsoluteTiming[
     Join[
       Map[Apply[d[[#1, #2, #3]] &, #] &, cube[[1 ;; 99]]],
       Map[Apply[d[[#1, #2, #3]] &, #] &, cube[[100 ;; 125]]]
       ];

 ]

{0., Null}
```

Why is there a huge performance gap? An how do I avoid it except splitting my list?

Comment: Btw your `cube` is equal to `Tuples[Range[5],3]`, just so you know :).

Comment: @TeakeNutma I bet `...` here really means `{2,9,12},{tweedledee,tweedledum, "tweedleDUN"}`. This reminds me of a book by a mathematician I once read which pointed out a remarkable device that physicists have come up with, namely, $\ldots$, which allows them to solve practically any problem simply by omission.

Comment: Can you show what `d` is? and isn't this the same : `Map[d[[Sequence @@ #]] &, cube]`?  I cant reproduce this slowness even on much larger lists.

Comment: @george2079 I've added an example in my answer, take a look

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at `SystemOptions[]`, like so,

```
Column[
 OpenerView /@
  (Replace[SystemOptions[], Rule[x_, y_] -> List[x, y],
     1])
 ]
```

you see that under `CompileOptions`, if you click on the triangle to open it,

[image]

there is an option `"MapCompileLength" -> 100`. Set it to eg 10 and see it it helps (do `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength" -> 10}]`).

This option determines the length of the list above which Mathematica (tries to) compile the function to be mapped.

EDIT: Example:

Here's some data:

```
Length[cube = Tuples[Range[10], 4]]
```

And here's a function which is a) inefficient on purpose, b) designed to be compilable as-is (that's why I localise `s`, so that `Compile` will work).

```
d = (Module[{s = 0}, Do[s = s + #[[i]]^2, {i, Length@#}];s] &)
```

Now, set the auto-compilation length for `Map` to 100 (the default):

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength" -> 100}]
```

and now test:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
Quiet@BenchmarkPlot[d /@ # &, cube[[1 ;; #]] &, Range[90, 110]]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm dense today. Your example got *faster* at length 100, which I understand, but the OP's got **slower** at length 100, which I do not understand.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelE2 oops, no, I am dense! You're right. Well then the example is inapplicable. Maybe they should just set the length to infinity and see what happens.

Comment: @acl maybe the compilation itself is fairly expensive, and not worth the 'payoff'?

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon that's the only explanation I could think of, too. Let's see when/if we are shown the function. It might involve lots of subexpressions so that time is spent on optimizing them, for example.