# Sudden increase in timing when summing over 250 entries

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, summation, timing

I see a sudden increase of `Timing` by a factor of  thousands when I sum over 250 elements of a matrix rather than over 249.
So for instance, this table contains sums from 1 to 249 and it takes 0.0002s

```
Clear[vec, time];
vec = Table[i, {i, 100}, {j, 100}, {k, 300}];
time = Timing[
Table[Sum[vec[[i, j, k]], {k, 1, 249}], {i, 1}, {j, 1}]][[1]]; time
```

while if I go from 1 to 250

```
Clear[vec, time];
vec = Table[i, {i, 100}, {j, 100}, {k, 300}];
time = Timing[
Table[Sum[vec[[i, j, k]], {k, 1, 250}], {i, 1}, {j, 1}]][[1]]; time
```

it takes 1.4s. The huge increase occurs regardless of the content of `vec`, regardless of the upper limits of `i`,`j`, and it does not depend on whether I go from 1 to 250 or from 2 to 251, provided it's at least 250 entries. So if I sum from 2 to 250, it's back to 0.0002s. It depends instead on the size of `vec` (that is why I create a much larger matrix `vec` than actually needed in the sum). Can anybody reproduce this behavior? Any suggestion?

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54996/16) seems closely related. And setting the option @Karsten mentions does work. This looks like something to report to support.

Comment: @Karsten thanks, it works! A search of SumCompileLength on the Help->Documentation center returns no results, and CompileOptions returns useless (for me) information.

Comment: (note that the example I give in my answer to the other question doesn't demonstrate what you are seeing, but the solution is indeed to increase the option mentioned)

Comment: try `"CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions[]` or look at the way they're displayed in my answer to the other question

Comment: I can't believe that such a common operation like summing over more than 250 entries require tweaking the SetSystemOptions, which the manual recommend not to modify:

Comment: It should not :) but it seems to do that in v9 as well

Comment: @acl thanks! I see that these SystemOptions can be really crucial at times. Need to remember that!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The default `SumCompileLength` is 250.
You can increase this number for example to 500 using

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 500}]
```

or to infinity using

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> ∞}]
```

---

### What is `"SumCompileLength"` for?

For sums with a finite number of at least `"SumCompileLength"` elements autocompilation will be used to compute the sum.

### Visualization and explanation

For a `Sum` with very simple summands, `Sum[k, {k, 1, n}]`, the timings as a function of the number of elements `n` using the default settings

```
SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "SumCompileLength"]
```

$\ $`{"CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 250}}`

can be visualized with

```
defaultTimings = First@AbsoluteTiming[Sum[k, {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~500;

ListPlot[defaultTimings, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> "defaultTimings: \"SumCompileLength\"\[Rule]250"]
```

[image: defaultTimings]

As described by the OP there is a huge jump in the timings at 250 elements. This is due to the fact that the time needed to perform the autocompilation is longer than the time saved by using the autocompiled version. Additionally one can observe that the slope is less steep for more than 250 elements, because, after the autocompilation is done, using the autocompiled version is actually faster than using the non-autocompiled version.

### When `"SumCompileLength"` should not be increased

For the very simple summand given in the question and for 250 and some more elements increasing `"SumCompileLength"` as shown in the beginning of this answer reduces the time needed to compute the `Sum`. However, it would be wrong to conclude that `"SumCompileLength"` should always be increased or set to infinity.

**1) Using the `Sum` multiple times**

```
do1 = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 250}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[RandomReal[]*Sum[k, {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~500);

do100Default = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 250}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Do[RandomReal[]*Sum[k, {k, 1, #}], {100}]]/100. &~Array~500);

do100SCL∞ = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> ∞}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Do[RandomReal[]*Sum[k, {k, 1, #}], {100}]]/100. &~Array~500);

do100SCL1 = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 1}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Do[RandomReal[]*Sum[k, {k, 1, #}], {100}]]/100. &~Array~500);

ListPlot[{do1, do100Default, do100SCL∞, do100SCL1}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> {"do1", "do100Default", "do100SCL∞]", "do100SCL1"}]
```

[image: do1-do100]

In situations where the autocompiled version of the `Sum` can be reused, it is advantageous to reduce `"SumCompileLength"`.

**2) `Sum` over a huge number of elements**

```
scl250 = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 250}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Sum[k, {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~1000);

scl1 = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 1}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Sum[k, {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~1000);

scl∞ = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> ∞}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Sum[k, {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~1000);

ListPlot[{scl250, scl1, scl∞}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> {"\"SumCompileLength\" \[Rule] 250", 
   "\"SumCompileLength\" \[Rule] 1", "\"SumCompileLength\" \[Rule] ∞"}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{550, 0}, {550, 1}}]}]
```

[image: upTo1000lElements]

For this example using autocompilation is already beneficial for more than approx. 550 elements.

**3) Computational expensive, compilable summands**
For example [`LogGamma`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogGamma.html?q=LogGamma) is a [compilable function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/18476) that is computational more expensive than the previous example.

```
scl250 = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 250}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Sum[N@LogGamma[k], {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~350);

scl1 = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> 1}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Sum[N@LogGamma[k], {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~350);

scl∞ = (SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> ∞}]; 
   First@AbsoluteTiming[Sum[N@LogGamma[k], {k, 1, #}]] &~Array~350);

ListPlot[{scl250, scl1, scl∞}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> {"\"SumCompileLength\" \[Rule] 250", 
   "\"SumCompileLength\" \[Rule] 1", "\"SumCompileLength\" \[Rule] ∞"}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{50, 0}, {50, 1}}]}]
```

[image: LogGamma]

Here the autocompiled version already starts to outperform the non-autocompiled version at about 50 elements.

Comment: What could be the drawbacks of increasing `SumCompileLength`?

Comment: @anderstood For the example given in the question, I'm not aware of any drawbacks. Increasing `SumCompileLength` will be disadvantageous in situations, where compiling the function of the summands causes a speed increase and not a speed decrease as for the very simple summands in the example given in the question. Maybe I'll elaborate on that tomorrow.

Comment: You might be interested in reading my recently added answer to this question where relate a funny observation.

Comment: @anderstood I significantly extended my answer. Now it should not only address the problem described in the OP, but also provide a better general understanding of the `"*CompileLength"` `SystemOptions`.

Comment: Very clear, thank you! That explains the behaviour of my example (Case 1: table of table).

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to change the system options just to make `Sum` auto-compile, then you could instead replace `Sum` by `Total`:

```
Clear[vec, time];
vec = Table[i, {i, 100}, {j, 100}, {k, 300}];
time = Timing[
   Table[Total[vec[[i, j, 1 ;; 250]]], {i, 1}, {j, 1}]][[1]]; time
```

The resulting timing doesn't show any significant difference between `249` and `250`, and is just as fast as your first example.

Comment: This is almost always a good idea if what you want to do is a numerical sum.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp) in a comment to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95855/why-is-this-function-taking-so-much-more-time-when-its-argument-reaches-250), this is a humble contribution. The OP has already been answered. This is not answer *per se* but shows that `CompileLength` should not always be increased, and should even sometimes be reduced for significant speed gain.

Consider the following (stupid) function:

```
x1 = Function[{n, T, t}, (Table[Cos[(Mod[t, T] - T/2)]/Sin[T/2.], {j, 1, n}])[[1]]];
times249 = Table[x1[249, 123, 3] // AbsoluteTiming, {i, 1, 100}][[All, 1]];
times250 = Table[x1[250, 123, 3] // AbsoluteTiming, {i, 1, 100}][[All, 1]];
ListPlot[{times249, times250}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 0.005}}]
```

Output:

[image]

It appears that this time, the function `x1` takes way more time for values ***below*** 250. This can be corrected using

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 1}]
```

Note the value has to be taken lower than 250, contrary to the previous example. The conclusion is, do not increase the values of `CompileOptions` without thinking, or at least trying.