# Why is this function taking so much more time when its argument reaches 250?

Tags: performance-tuning, timing

I am observing something which I do not understand with the following function `function`:

```
kelem={{n+0.,-n},{-n,n}};
assembleMatrice[diagK_]:=Block[{matrice},
  matrice=Sum[ArrayPad[kelem,{(i-1),(n-i)}],{i,1,n}];
  matrice[[2;;-1,2;;-1]]]
function[n_]:=Block[{},
  klist = ConstantArray[n+0.,n];
  mlist = ConstantArray[1./n,n];
  k = assembleMatrice[klist];
  m = DiagonalMatrix[mlist];
  b = Inverse[MatrixPower[m,.5]].MatrixPower[k,.5];
  q = Transpose@Eigenvectors[b.Transpose@b];
  xp:=Sum[q[[n,i]],{i,1,n}];]
```

When I evaluate `AbsoluteTiming[function[n]]` for $n\in\{1,\dots,249\}$, the time returned evolves smoothly. But why does it takes 50 times longer when $n$ reaches $250$?

Illustration:

```
Table[Block[{}, function[n]; AbsoluteTiming[xp;]], {n, 248, 252}][[All, 1]]
(* output: {0.000205, 0.000229, 0.014314, 0.014379, 0.014414} *)
```

You see that the difference between the third and second term, corresponding to $n$ reaching $250$, is much higher than the other differences.

Note: This is a MWE. `xp` is actually much more complicated than this, so I am not asking for better ways to calculate this `xp`. I am intersted in optimised definitions for the other variables though, if any.

---

**Edit** 
I just stumbled upon an interesting (for me...) observation.

Consider the following (stupid) function:

```
x1 = Function[{n, T, t}, (Table[Cos[(Mod[t, T] - T/2)]/Sin[T/2.], {j, 1, n}])[[1]]];
times249 = Table[x1[249, 123, 3] // AbsoluteTiming, {i, 1, 100}][[All, 1]];
times250 = Table[x1[250, 123, 3] // AbsoluteTiming, {i, 1, 100}][[All, 1]];
ListPlot[{times249, times250}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 0.005}}]
```

Output:

[image]

It appears that this time, the function `x1` takes way more time for values ***below*** 250. This can corrected using

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 1}]
```

Note the the value has to be taken lower than 250, contrary to the previous example. The conclusion is, do not increase the values of `CompileOptions` without thinking, or at least trying.

Comment: [`(55242)`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55242/sudden-increase-in-timing-when-summing-over-250-entries?rq=1)

Comment: Try and see if the solution actually works -- if it does it will just get flagged as a duplicate

Comment: Both answers give good result, especially changing `SumCompileLength`. Using `Total@Table` instead of `Sum` results in a much faster computation than the OP but still shows a threshold at 250.

Comment: Glad it works good :)

Comment: @Sektor I asked the author of the accepted answer if there is any drawback of (reasonably) increasing `SumCompileLength`. I am mentionning it here to get a wider audience.

Comment: Voting to reopen, as the OP contributed some useful observations in the edit. Better yet, I'd suggest to include these latest observations as an answer to the Q marked duplicate, as it's a nice example of the case where one *shouldn't* increase the `CompileLength`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP OK, done.