# Benchmarking: unexplained switching between high and low performance

Tags: timing, system-performance, benchmarking

***tl;dr*** I am trying to accurately benchmark some vectorized operations, and compare them between systems.  But benchmarking is hard to do well, and I am getting inconsistent results: performance is switching, apparently randomly, between "slow" and "fast". **Why?** — [Link to Woflram Community version.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1047708)

Here is some code that benchmarks adding two packed arrays of size `n`, where `n` is just above a million.  The timing is measured 5 times, to ensure consistency, then `n` is increased a bit, then the summation is timed again, etc.  The whole benchmark is repeated twice.

```
Table[
 n = 1000000 + k;
 SeedRandom[120];
 a = RandomReal[1, n];
 b = RandomReal[1, n];
 {k, Table[First@RepeatedTiming[a + b;], {5}]},
 {2}, {k, 20000, 200000, 20000}
 ]
```

The results are below.  In each row, the first number is the array size, the rest are the 5 timings.

```
{{ {20000, {0.000799, 0.000801, 0.000797, 0.000804, 0.000800}}, 
   {40000, {0.00224, 0.00225, 0.00223, 0.00224, 0.00223}}, 
   {60000, {0.00226, 0.00226, 0.00227, 0.00226, 0.00226}}, 
   {80000, {0.00229, 0.00229, 0.00229, 0.00229, 0.00229}}, 
  {100000, {0.00087, 0.000868, 0.000874, 0.000873, 0.00089}}, 
  {120000, {0.00235, 0.00236, 0.00235, 0.00236, 0.00235}}, 
  {140000, {0.00240, 0.00240, 0.00240, 0.00239, 0.00240}}, 
  {160000, {0.00245, 0.00246, 0.00245, 0.00246, 0.00245}}, 
  {180000, {0.00097, 0.000964, 0.000965, 0.000961, 0.000963}}, 
  {200000, {0.00255, 0.00258, 0.00254, 0.00256, 0.00254}}}, 

   {{20000, {0.00224, 0.00224, 0.00224, 0.00220, 0.00221}}, 
    {40000, {0.00224, 0.00224, 0.00223, 0.00224, 0.00223}},
    {60000, {0.00227, 0.00227, 0.00227, 0.00226, 0.00227}},
    {80000, {0.00234, 0.00235, 0.00233, 0.00230, 0.00230}},
   {100000, {0.00233, 0.00232, 0.00232, 0.00233, 0.00233}}, 
   {120000, {0.00234, 0.00238, 0.00235, 0.00239, 0.00237}}, 
   {140000, {0.00238, 0.00238, 0.00238, 0.00238, 0.00238}}, 
   {160000, {0.00247, 0.00245, 0.00245, 0.00246, 0.00245}}, 
   {180000, {0.000965, 0.000961, 0.000962, 0.000967, 0.000968}}, 
   {200000, {0.00254, 0.00259, 0.00255, 0.00254, 0.00254}}}}
```

Things to notice:

- The 5 timings for the same array are always consistent.
- The timings are generally proportional to the array size.
- However, I see some "fast" (about 0.0008 s) and some "slow" (about 0.002 s) timings.
- Between the two runs, it is not always the same array size that is fast. Look at 20,000, 80,000 and 180,000 in the first run and 180,000 in the second run.  These change randomly between runs.
- "Slow" and "fast" differ by a very significant factor of about 2.5-2.6.

**Why do I see this switching between fast and slow timing?  What is causing it?**  It prevents me from getting consistent benchmark results.

[image]

---

The measurements were done with Mathematica 11.1.0 on a 2014 MacBook Pro (`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz`, 4 cores) connected to AC power.  [Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) is disabled using [this tool](https://github.com/rugarciap/Turbo-Boost-Switcher).

I closed other programs as much as possible (but there are always many background tasks on a modern OS).

---

You might think that such short timings are not relevant in real-world applications. But remember that `RepeatedTiming` repeats the operation enough times to run for at least a second.  I still get some fast timings if I increase this to as many as 15 seconds, or if I run the test many times consecutively.

I compared `RepeatedTiming` with `AbsoluteTiming@Do[..., {bigNumber}]`, and there is no difference (other than the occasional fast-slow switching).

I noticed that longer arrays are less likely to produce fast timings than shorter ones, but I am not sure. I also noticed that running a long one tends to cause the subsequent short one to be slow again.  Due to the fickle nature of the results, it is hard to be sure about these things.

---

On first sight, this may not look like a Mathematica question.  But benchmarking is hard, and many things can go wrong.  If I post it on another site, people may rightfully suspect that it is something specific to Mathematica that is causing it.

I believe that vector arithmetic is parallelized in Mathematica. There is an interesting talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzjhFF0wJiw) by Mark Sofroniou from WTC2016, which also discusses how the stragety used to distribute parlallel threads between cores can have a significant impact on performance.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's modified code by Sander Huisman on Wolfram Community.  This makes it easier to reproduce the slow-fast pattern.  It also shows another effect: when evaluating the same thing multiple times, it gets slower with each evaluation.

```
timings = Table[n = 1000000 + 8000 j;
  SeedRandom[120];
  a = RandomReal[1, n];
  b = RandomReal[1, n];
  First@AbsoluteTiming[Do[a + b;, {500}]], {10}, {j, 20}]
ListPlot[Flatten[timings], PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

With Turbo Boost turn on on my machine:

[image]

With Turbo Boost off:

[image]

Running this takes a long time because I wanted to have timings that are over a second, for reliability.  To just try this out, reduce the `{500}` to `{50}` in the `Do` loop.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I did a comparison with MATLAB 2017a.  I believe that both Mathematica and MATLAB use the MKL, and this should perform similarly on vector arithmetic.

```matlab
a=rand(1,1000000);
b=rand(1,1000000);

tic; for i=1:1000
c=a+b;
end;toc
```

The timing (divided by 1000 to account for the repetitions) is 0.00065 s.  This happens to be the same as the "fast" timing I get from Mathematica.  But in MATLAB, I get the "fast" timing consistently.

This suggests that what I see is "a bug" in Mathematica, or rather that there is a potential for a speedup by a factor of 2.5 or more on my hardware and OS.

Comment: No such problem on my computer. Specs: `Windows`, `Mathematica 11.0.1` and `Intel i7-6560U`. On my computer the timing difference is approximately 5%.

Comment: @Wjx Sometimes I only get the slow one.  It is worth trying other array sizes as well, especially smaller ones. Are you using a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: Yup, I only got the slow one too. I ran your code two times, no significant timing difference in both trial.

Comment: I've tried smaller dataset now, still no significant difference in timing ;) I'm using my laptop.

Comment: @Wjx It could be OS-dependent too. I can get the fast timing more easily if I first evaluate this in a fresh kernel: `n = 1000000;
SeedRandom[42];
a = RandomReal[1, n];
b = RandomReal[1, n];`, and then I evaluate this a few seconds later: `RepeatedTiming[a + b;]`

Comment: I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQsp8.png) on my Lenovo R500 laptop (Intel Core 2 Duo P8400, 2266 MHz)  connected to AC power and running Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Could be timing granularity. Could be vagaries of 8 vs 16 byte alignment (affects perhaps what registers get used for the arithmetic).

Comment: @Daniel By timing granularity, do you mean the resolution of the timer?  I am not completely sure what `RepeatedTiming` does, but this is reproducible with `First@AbsoluteTiming@Do[expr, {many}]/many` in cases when `many` is big enough for the total timing to be longer than a second.  Thus it should not be affected by the resolution of the timer.

Comment: Yes I meant what you thought. Looking a bit more I am also now of the opinion that it is not a granularity issue. It might or might not be an issue in `RepeatedTiming` internals. I'm leaning toward it being determined by packed array byte alignment, but that is still just a guess.

Comment: @Wjx Can you try the new code at the end of the post, please?  You can reduce 500 repetitions to only 50 to speed things up.

Comment: @Daniel The original reason why I made detailed benchmarks was that I thought I saw clear differences between RepeatedTiming and AbsoluteTiming.  But it turned out that that is not the case. The differences were due to the slow-fast pattern I am asking here.  I do not think that there is any problem with RepeatedTiming.  I am quite confident that it gives correct results (or at least results that fully agree with AbsoluteTiming for as long as the time is long enough).  Maybe it's the byte alignment then.

Comment: @Daniel Even if it is about alignment, the striking thing is that there seems to be a potential for a very significant 2.5x speedup (at least on this OS and hardware, and for this specific operation). I just tried MATLAB, and it consistently gives same timing I get for the "fast" case in Mathematica.  As I understand, both MATLAB and Mathematica use the MKL for this sort of operation, and in the past (years ago) I had the impression that Mma and MATLAB releases from the same year usually performed similarly.

Comment: Just a comment on `RepeatedTiming` vs. `AbsoluteTiming`: `RepeatedTiming` and `AbsoluteTiming@Do[..., {bigNumber}]` should give you the same result, if the implementation of `RepeatedTiming` did not change from when it was part of `GeneralUtilities`. However, using something like `AbsoluteTiming@Do[...]` is problematic when autocompiling takes place, as the compiled version is reused. (see, e.g., the **2)** part [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55243/18476)).

Comment: @Szabolcs I still get consistent timing...... Always the slow one.

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you tired switching off hyper-threading in the BIOS?

Comment: @user21 I am using OS X 10.12.4 (Sierra). It seems that HyperThreading can be disabled using the Instruments.app tool that comes with Xcode. It does not make a difference to the results.  The number of active cores can also be adjusted with this tool. I will play with this in the evening.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if this is Mac only issue, as there the MKL is linked in a different manner than other OSes. Has anyone with a non Mac reproduced this?

Comment: @user21 Not that I know of.  The only other people who could reproduce it were also using a Mac.  In the past, I also had the general impression that Mathematica is slowest on Mac.  Many operations were faster on Windows or Linux inside of VirtualBox than running directly on OS X. This was a long time ago, and on a slightly different machine than what I am using now.

Comment: @user21 I still have a M11.0.1 installation in a Linux VirtualBox on the same computer where I did these benchmarks.  I only have 2 cores assigned to it (out of 8 virtual ones available on this 4-physical-core machine).  The typical timing for `First@AbsoluteTiming@Do[a + b;, {1000}]/1000` on Linux is just below 0.0009 seconds, which is significantly faster than the "slow" timing on OS X (about 0.002) but slower than the "fast" timing (0.00065 s)—this has to be due to fewer cores being available.  It really seems like something is not working right on Mac.

Comment: @Szabolcs I would be curious if there is any improvement if the timing is measured with ``Internal`ArithmeticTiming[Plus, a, b]``.

Comment: @ilian Yes.  [I seem to get the "fast" timing.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SkemZ.png)  What does that mean?  I had to try many times because right now Mathematica was in the mood of evaluating this quickly even with a plain `a+b;`.  But then finally it did switch back to the "slow" timing, yet `ArithmeticTiming` keeps giving the "fast" number.

Comment: @ilian Have you been able to reproduce this internally?  What does it mean that the result from ``Internal`ArithmeticTiming`` is always fast?

Comment: It's a low-level method to (almost) directly time the actual operation, so this likely means the arithmetic is performing as expected while the fluctuations have more to do with things like going through the evaluator, repeatedly allocating memory for the result and/or caching.  Why Mac would be different from other operating systems is still a bit of an open question.

Comment: Get a utility that logs cpu frequency during runs. See if it's throttling. This looks suspiciously like thermal throttling, based on others getting more consistent timings.

Answer (score -1):

You did supply any details on your platform.  Mine is 
Windows 10, Prof, Anniversary Update, 64-bit
Intel Xeon CPU E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10GHz, 4 Core(s), no Hyperthreading
32 GB ECC RAM memory
Mathematica 11.0

I don't know how to insert code on StackExchange and I cannot find an explanation anywhere on how to do it, so I must describe what I did.

I ran your code, and then added

```
Flatten[%, 1]
Map[Function[e, {First@e, First@First@Rest@e}], %]
ListPlot[%]
```

And Mathematica displayed an almost perfect straight line: Running times are almost perfectly a function of array size, albeit my times are about twice yours, and I don't see any "miracle results" that complete an iteration in a few hundreds of microseconds.

You did not say how much memory you have, but I speculate that your widely varying results could be explained by the Mathematica kernel's need to push virtual memory out to disk, and or garbage collection when the kernel runs out of memory.  I don't mean to brag, but investing in 32 GB of main memory has solved many problems for me.

Comment: "You did supply any details on your platform" <- Did you mean to say "You did *not* ..."?  The details are in the question.  All the evidence so far points towards this being an OS X-only issue, so it is not surprising that you do not see it on Windows. I do not see how this could have anything to do with memory, given that a million floating point numbers only take up 8 MB.  There are also no "miracle results" here, only unreasonably slow ones (2.5 times slower than MATLAB).