# Fast pairwise SameQ test of an ordered list

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

I have an ordered list of $N$ numbers, and I want to find out whether adjacent numbers are [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) or not, returning a list of 0s and 1s of length $N-1$. One approach is something like:

```
pairwiseBoole[y_] := Boole[SameQ @@@ Transpose[{Rest[y],Most[y]}]]
```

but this is extremely slow:

```
data = Union @ RandomReal[E + {0, 10^-7}, 10^6];
Length[data]

res = pairwiseBoole[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
Count[res, 0]
```

> 997747
>
> {0.640326, Null}
>
> 993254

If I naively compile this, I can increase the speed by an order of magnitude, but I think it should be possible to write a function that is still faster, since:

```
Rest[y] - Most[y]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.009215, Null}

and [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) is true as long as they only differ in their last binary digit (note that one might need to know about `` Internal`$SameQTolerance ``).

How can I perform this computation as quickly as possible?

**Update**

Based on the answers/comments, I should have provided a better example, one where the fact that [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) uses a relative and not absolute tolerance plays a more important role. So, the kind of data I'm using is more similar to the following *(corrected to output a packed array thanks to @Szabolcs)*:

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray @ Union[
    RandomChoice[100 Sin[Subdivide[0, 7, 40]], 10^6] +
    RandomReal[{0, 10^-7}, 10^6]
];
```

And, it is vital that the output is the same as what one would get using pairwise [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) on list elements. Only results that produce the same output as pairwiseBoole are acceptable.

**My compiled version**

By the way, here is the compiled version that I had come up with:

```
pairwiseBooleC = Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},
    Table[Boole[SameQ[x[[i]], x[[i+1]]]], {i, Length[x]-1}]
];
```

and a comparison with my `pairwiseBoole`:

```
r1 = pairwiseBoole[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = pairwiseBooleC[data]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.63, Null}
>
> {0.042, Null}
>
> True

Some background, I am writing a [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember) type function that can handle multiple regions, returning which region a point belongs to. In order to get edge cases correct it is vital that I use something equivalent to [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) when comparing adjacent elements.

Comment: Why not ``Boole[Developer`PartitionMap[Apply[SameQ], y, 2, 1]]``?

Comment: Maybe something based on `1 - Unitize[Rest[data] - Most[data]]`?  It would need to be investigated how `Unitize` checks for zeros (with `==`, with `===` or with a different tolerance than either of these two).  How important is it to you to have precisely the same tolerance as `SameQ`?

Comment: Why not start with `Differences`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's slower than `Rest[data] - Most[data]` :-( Probably Differences is implemented naïvely, while `Rest[data] - Most[data]` makes use of the full power of vector arithmetic though the MKL.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's a surprise; it didn't use to be the case.

Comment: With [BoolEval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/12), the above could be written more readable as `BoolEval[Rest[data] == Most[data]]`, with minimal performance degradation. Also, I just realize that the difference based method can't easily reproduce the tolerance behaviour of `SameQ` (because it uses relative, not absolute tolerances).

Comment: `Split[data]` is only 3.5 times faster than `pairwiseBoole`.  Perhaps this is the limit of what can be achieved when using `SameQ` instead of arithmetic tricks ...  (`Split` does unpack though, which takes significant time.)

Comment: @Szabolcs excellent point regarding tolerance

Comment: Systems like MATLAB or numpy are very good at vectorized computation.  They can make use of SIMD instructions and multi-threading while comparing two arrays (`==` or `>`).  Mathematica cannot do this.  The algorithmically equivalent constructs (e.g. `MapThread[compare, {arr1, arr2}]`) are *much* slower in Mathematica.  A workaround is to translate the comparisons into vector arithmetic (`Subtract`, `Unitize`, `UnitStep`, etc.), which is just as fast in Mathematica as in MATLAB/numpy.  Unfortunately, such code is both hard to read and write. My BoolEval package tries to fix this ...

Comment: ... by providing a convenient notation in terms of `==`, `>`, and translating that into arithmetic transparently.  But your example shows that arithmetic isn't really a good replacement for such tasks: it changes the tolerance behaviour.  I think the lack of vectorized comparisons is a significant handicap for Mathematica.  Years ago I sent suggestions to support to improve this situation, but I don't really have any hope that anything will happen ...

Comment: Observations: The new `data` you provided is not packed, which causes `Rest[data] - Most[data];` to be slower than `pairwiseBooleC` on this. (This really confused me.) This gives a marginal speedup compared to `pairwiseBooleC`: `cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, Boole[x === y], 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]; cf[Rest[data], Most[data]]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, I forgot about packing. Also, your `Compile` version is a nice improvement, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

On my computer simple `LibraryFunction`, that compares subsequent elements in a loop, is fastest.

```
pairwiseBooleJkuczm = Last@Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}},
  Table[
    Boole[Compile`GetElement[data, i] === Compile`GetElement[data, i + 1]],
    {i, Length@data - 1}
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineIntegerOverflow" -> False, "CompareWithTolerance" -> True}
];

SeedRandom@0;
data = Developer`ToPackedArray@
   Union[RandomChoice[100 Sin[Subdivide[0, 7, 40]], 10^6] + 
     RandomReal[{0, 10^-7}, 10^6]];

(res1 = pairwiseBoole@data) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(res2 = pairwiseBooleC@data) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(res3 = pairwiseBooleJkuczm@data) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
res1 === res2 === res3
(* {0.563, 175791672} *)
(* {0.044,  15981232} *)
(* {0.013,   7990696} *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: One must use a relative tolerance. Please see my update for a more representative data sample.

Comment: @CarlWoll I've changed comparison to to `SameQ` with `"CompareWithTolerance" -> True`, which, I believe, works the same as uncompiled `SameQ` on machine reals.

Comment: Yes, that works, but we lose some of the speed advantage that you had before. Possibly that's related to the `RuntimeOptions` you needed to include. I came up with an alternate approach in my answer that avoids those `RuntimeOptions` but perhaps I've introduced a bug by doing so.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an approach assuming that the [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) tolerance is not changed from its default.

**\$MachineEpsilon**

`$MachineEpsilon` is the smallest number that when added to `1.` produces a different number. This means that `1.` and `1.+ $MachineEpsilon` will differ by 1 in the last bit of the base 2 representation of the mantissa. Hence the two numbers will satisfy the [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) predicate. Any larger numbers will not. This suggests the following algorithm for deciding the [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) predicate:

**Algorithm**

Let $l$ and $u$ be two numbers to be compared, with $l<u$. Then, the [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ) predicate should be equivalent to:

$$\frac{u - l}{\left|u\right|} \le \epsilon$$

We can rewrite this as:

$$\epsilon \left|u\right| + (l-u) \ge 0$$

Finally, if we use a Heaviside theta function where `0.` is mapped to `1`, then we can use the following arithmetical expression:

$$\theta(\epsilon \left|u\right| + (l-u))$$

which will return 1 if $l$ and $u$ are [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ), and 0 otherwise.  I'm not sure about the correctness of this algorithm, but it passes all of the tests that I could think of.

**Mathematica implementation**

Here is the Mathematica implementation:

```
pairwiseSameQ[data_] := With[{u=Rest[data], l=Most[data]},
    UnitStep[$MachineEpsilon Abs[u] + (l-u)]
]
```

**Tests**

Let's compare this function to my slow function:

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray @ Union[
    RandomChoice[100 Sin[Subdivide[0,7,40]], 10^6] + 
    RandomReal[{0, 10^-7}, 10^6]
];

r1 = pairwiseBoole[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = pairwiseSameQ[data]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.651, Null}
>
> {0.0109, Null}
>
> True

We get the same results, and the function is faster than the [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) alternatives in the other answers. What happens if we [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) this approach?

**Compile**

Following @jkuczm's approach, a compiled version might look like:

```
pairwiseSameQC = With[{e=$MachineEpsilon},
    Last @ Compile[{{d, _Real, 1}},
        Table[
            Boole[e Abs[Compile`GetElement[d,i+1]]>=(Compile`GetElement[d,i+1]-Compile`GetElement[d,i])],
            {i, Length@d-1}
        ],
        CompilationTarget->"C",
        RuntimeOptions->"Speed"
    ]
];
```

One final comparison:

```
r3 = pairwiseSameQC[data]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.0016, Null}
>
> True

Now, that's pretty fast!

Answer (score 6):

Best so far is `BoolEval[Rest[y] == Most[y]]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
data = Union @ RandomReal[E + {0, 10^-7}, 10^6];
```

---

```
pwb1[y_] := Boole[SameQ @@@ Transpose[{Rest[y], Most[y]}]]

pwb1[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.730, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb2[y_] := Inner[Boole @* SameQ, Rest[y], Most[y], List]

pwb2[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.9117, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb3[y_] := Boole @ Inner[SameQ, Rest[y], Most[y], List]

pwb3[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.66, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb4[y_] := Boole[Developer`PartitionMap[SameQ, y, 2, 1]]

pwb4[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.55, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb5[y_] := Unitize @ Differences[y]

pwb5[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.024, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb6[y_] := 1 - Unitize @ Differences[y]

pwb6[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0269, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb7[y_] := 1 - Unitize[Rest[y] - Most[y]]

pwb7[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0203, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb8[y_] := 1 - Unitize[Rest[y] - Most[y], 1*^-17]

pwb8[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0233, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb9[y_] := ListConvolve[{1, 1}, y, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, SameQ]

pwb9[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.712, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb10[y_] := BoolEval[Rest[y] == Most[y]]

pwb10[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00671, Null} *)
```

---

```
pwb11[y_] := Subtract[1, Unitize[Subtract[Rest[y], Most[y]]]]

pwb11[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0165, Null} *)
```

Comment: Do you care if they give the same output?  I'm finding e.g. pwb1 not equal to the results of 6 or 7.  e.g. with resX=pwbX[data];   I'm finding: `res6 === res7 === 1 - res5 === 1 - res4` and `res1 === res2 === res3`, but the two sets of results are not equivalent.

Comment: @JohnJosephM.Carrasco  `pwb5` clearly  has a reverse logic, and I assume the other difference are about the tolerances, as discussed by Szabolcs  and Mr.Wizard. This is a *community wiki* answer, feel free to edit to improve and clarify. Also add your own benchmarks.

Comment: I don't have anything to add about the performance (all my games were much slower), just suggesting that the tolerance difference in output should be possibly emphasized in answer (obvious to all the cognoscenti , but ...)

Comment: Notice that `Unitize[x,dx]` does allow for specific tolerance specifications.

Comment: Specifying tolerance for `Unitize` seems to add about 25% to computation time (on my system). Perhaps that should be taken into consideration?

Comment: Can you include `ListConvolve[{1, 1}, y, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, SameQ]` as well?

Comment: Note that `a - b` is parsed to `Plus[a, Times[-1, b]]` usually this doesn't matter, but for vectorized operations on large arrays `Subtract[a, b]` is faster. So `Subtract[1, Unitize[Subtract[Rest@data, Most@data]]]` should be faster than `1 - Unitize[Rest[data] - Most[data]]`.

Comment: That's weird because BoolEval (i.e. pwb10) translates to pwb11.  It should be slightly slower than pwb11 (due to extra overhead), and it is slower on my machine.

Comment: @rhermans `decode.m` returns 404 :-(  I have a half-written blog post on BoolEval which I could not publish because of [this performance inconsistency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141350/12).  Could it be affecting you?

Comment: It is vital that the output is the same as what one gets with `pwb1`, so only `pwb1`, `pwb2` and `pwb3` provide acceptable answers, and I'm hopeful that there is an answer that is quite a bit faster.