# Numerical Join of two sets of vectors ignoring repeats

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, algorithm

I have two sets of numerical vectors which can be either `Real` or `Complex` and I want to combine them together, ignoring repeats. 
Up until now I have been joining the two sets together and using Oleksander R.'s `compiledUnion` from [How to remove duplicates from set of machine precision 2D points?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-set-of-machine-precision-2d-points).

Example code for what I'm doing at the moment is something like:

```
a = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]
a = RandomChoice[a, 100]
b = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]
b = RandomChoice[b, 100]
compiledUnion[Join[a,b]]
```

I think I can actually get out a little bit more efficiency from this however. I know that my first set of vectors already has repeats removed, and is generally larger than the second set. So I was thinking that I could somehow use this as a reference and then I would only have to compare the elements from the second set against the first set rather than comparing all elements together. I guess it would make sense to also sort the shorter second set.

So setting up roughly the variables I'm working with would be something like this:

```
a = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];
a = RandomChoice[a, 1000];
a = compiledUnion[a];
b = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
b = RandomChoice[b, 10];
```

Then what I would guess is that I would also run `compiledUnion` on `b`, and then I would want something like a `compiledUnionJoin[a,b]` which reduces the total number of operations compared to just  `compiledUnion[Join[a,b]]`

I think that actually implementing this is a bit beyond my current programming skills however. Does anybody know of a good way to do it? Or perhaps my solution to this problem is not optimal and somebody else can think of a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use slightly adapted version of merge step of merge sort. For lists with lengths $n_1$ and $n_2$, where first is already sorted, sorting second list and merging it with first should run in $O(n_1 + n_2\log n_2)$ time.

Since we'll be compiling two versions of our function for `Real` and for `Complex` arguments, and each requires slightly different comparisons let's use [simple quoting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134916/14303) to simplify code building.

```
ClearAll[quote, unquote, eval]
SetAttributes[{quote, unquote}, HoldAllComplete]
quote@expr : Except@_Symbol :=
    Unevaluated@expr /. {x : _unquote | _quote :> x, s_Symbol -> quote@s}
unquote@args___ := args
eval = # /. HoldPattern@quote@s_ :> s &;
```

Some type dependent code generating functions:

```
inline // ClearAll
inline // Attributes = HoldAllComplete;

inline[a_[[i_]] > b_[[j_]], Real] :=
  quote[Compile`GetElement[a, i, 1] > Compile`GetElement[b, j, 1]]
inline[a_[[i_]] > b_[[j_]], Complex] := quote@With[
  {aEl = Compile`GetElement[a, i, 1], bEl = Compile`GetElement[b, j, 1]},
  Re@aEl > Re@bEl || Re@aEl == Re@bEl && Abs@Im@aEl > Abs@Im@bEl
]

inline[a_ != b_, eps_, Real] :=
  quote[Abs@Subtract[a, b] > eps Max[Abs@a, Abs@b]]
inline[a_ != b_, eps_, Complex] := quote[
  Abs@Subtract[Re@a, Re@b] > eps Max[Abs@Re@a, Abs@Re@b] ||
    Abs@Subtract[Im@a, Im@b] > eps Max[Abs@Im@a, Abs@Im@b]
]

inline[a_[[i_]] != b_[[j_]], eps_, m_, type_] :=
  quote@Module[{bool = False, aEl, bEl, l},
    Do[
      aEl = Compile`GetElement[a, i, l];
      bEl = Compile`GetElement[b, j, l];
      If[unquote@inline[aEl != bEl, eps, type],
        bool = True;
        Break[]
      ],
      {l, 1, m}
    ];
    bool
  ]

inline[a_[[i_]] = b_[[j_]], m_] := quote@Module[{l}, 
  Do[a[[i, l]] = Compile`GetElement[b, j, l], {l, 1, m}]
]
```

In above function "comparison with tolerance" was implemented "manually" as [shown by Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155057/14303).

Library function performing merging for given types:

```
compiledUnionJoin // ClearAll
compiledUnionJoin[type : Real | Complex] := compiledUnionJoin@type =
  eval@quote@Last@Compile[{{set, _type, 2}, {list, _type, 2}, {eps, _Real}}, 
    Module[{i, j, k, n, nSet, nSorted, m, lastFromSet, sorted, res},
      nSorted = Length@list;
      sorted = Sort@list;
      nSet = Length@set;
      n = nSet + nSorted;
      lastFromSet = False;
      i = j = k = 1;
      If[nSet > 0,
        m = Length@Compile`GetElement[set, i];
        If[nSorted > 0,
          m = Min[m, Length@Compile`GetElement[sorted, j]]
        ]
      (* else *),
        If[nSorted > 0,
          m = Length@Compile`GetElement[sorted, j];
        (* else *),
          m = 0;
        ]
      ];
      res = Table[unquote@Replace[type, {Real -> 0., Complex -> I 0.}], {n}, {m}];
      If[nSet > 0,
        If[nSorted > 0 && unquote@inline[set[[i]] > sorted[[j]], type],
          unquote@inline[res[[k]] = sorted[[j]], m];
          ++j
        (* else *),
          unquote@inline[res[[k]] = set[[i]], m];
          lastFromSet = True;
          ++i
        ]
      (* else *),
        If[nSorted > 0,
          unquote@inline[res[[k]] = sorted[[j]], m];
          ++j
        (* else *),
          k = 0
        ]
      ];
      While[i <= nSet && j <= nSorted,
        If[unquote@inline[set[[i]] > sorted[[j]], type],
          If[unquote@inline[res[[k]] != sorted[[j]], eps, m, type],
            ++k;
            unquote@inline[res[[k]] = sorted[[j]], m];
            lastFromSet = False
          ];
          ++j
        (* else *),
          If[lastFromSet || unquote@inline[res[[k]] != set[[i]], eps, m, type],
            ++k;
            unquote@inline[res[[k]] = set[[i]], m];
            lastFromSet = True
          ];
          ++i
        ]
      ];
      If[i <= nSet,
        If[lastFromSet || unquote@inline[res[[k]] != set[[i]], eps, m, type],
          ++k;
          unquote@inline[res[[k]] = set[[i]], m]
        ]
      ];
      Do[
        ++k;
        unquote@inline[res[[k]] = set[[l]], m]
        ,
        {l, i + 1, nSet}
      ];
      Do[
        If[unquote@inline[res[[k]] != sorted[[l]], eps, m, type],
          ++k;
          unquote@inline[res[[k]] = sorted[[l]], m]
        ],
        {l, j, nSorted}
      ];
      Take[res, k]
    ],
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

For comparison let's add `compiledUnion` from [answer by Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22091/14303) adapted to both types of arguments:

```
compiledUnion // ClearAll
compiledUnion[type : Real | Complex, tol_] := compiledUnion[type, tol] =
  Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = tol},
    Compile[{{r, _type, 2}},
      Block[{sorted = Sort@r, output, seen, current},
        output = Internal`Bag[seen = First@sorted, 1];
        Do[
          If[i != seen, Internal`StuffBag[output, seen = i, 1]],
          {i, sorted}
        ];
        Partition[Internal`BagPart[output, All], Length@seen]
      ],
      RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "CompareWithTolerance" -> True},
      CompilationTarget -> "C"
    ]
  ]
```

Let's pre-compile both functions for both argument types. `compiledUnion` requires comparison tolerance at compile time, we'll use `tol = 15`:

```
compiledUnionJoin@Real;
compiledUnionJoin@Complex;

tol = 15;
eps = 10^(tol - $MachinePrecision);

compiledUnion[Real, tol];
compiledUnion[Complex, tol];
```

Our test data, both real and complex:

```
SeedRandom@0
n = 2 10^6;
dataR = RandomChoice[RandomReal[1, {n, 2}], n];
dataC = RandomChoice[RandomComplex[1, {n, 2}], n];
```

Calling `compiledUnionJoin` with empty list as first argument is equivalent to `compiledUnion`:

```
res1 = compiledUnion[Real, tol]@dataR; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res2 = compiledUnionJoin[Real][{}, dataR, eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res1 === res2
res2 // Length
(* 0.780 *)
(* 0.671 *)
(* True *)
(* 1123205 *)

res1 = compiledUnion[Complex, tol]@dataC; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res2 = compiledUnionJoin[Complex][{}, dataC, eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res1 === res2
res2 // Length
(* 0.9354 *)
(* 0.8026 *)
(* True *)
(* 1124283 *)
```

`compiledUnionJoin` is slightly faster than `compiledUnion` when normalizing single list.

Now task from OP, joining two lists from which first is already sorted and free of duplicates.

```
a = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];
a = RandomChoice[a, 1000];
a = compiledUnion[Real, tol][a];
b = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
b = RandomChoice[b, 10];

res1 = compiledUnion[Real, tol]@Join[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res2 = compiledUnionJoin[Real][{}, Join[a, b], eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res3 = compiledUnionJoin[Real][a, b, eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res1 === res2 === res3
res3 // Length
(* 0.000079 *)
(* 0.0000385 *)
(* 0.0000189 *)
(* True *)
(* 565 *)
```

For our bigger test data:

```
a = Take[dataR, Round[.99 n]];
b = Drop[dataR, Round[.99 n]];
a = compiledUnionJoin[Real][{}, a, eps];
Length@a
Length@b
(* 1116705 *)
(*   20000 *)

res1 = compiledUnion[Real, tol]@Join[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res2 = compiledUnionJoin[Real][{}, Join[a, b], eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res3 = compiledUnionJoin[Real][a, b, eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res1 === res2 === res3
res3 // Length
(* 0.166 *)
(* 0.0897 *)
(* 0.0425 *)
(* True *)
(* 1122434 *)

a = Take[dataC, Round[.99 n]];
b = Drop[dataC, Round[.99 n]];
a = compiledUnionJoin[Complex][{}, a, eps];
Length@a
Length@b
(* 1117685 *)
(*   20000 *)

res1 = compiledUnion[Complex, tol]@Join[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res2 = compiledUnionJoin[Complex][{}, Join[a, b], eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res3 = compiledUnionJoin[Complex][a, b, eps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
res1 === res2 === res3
res3 // Length
(* 0.230 *)
(* 0.123 *)
(* 0.060 *)
(* True *)
(* 1123507 *)
```

If non-normalized list is about two orders of magnitude smaller than normalized one, as in OP, merging them using `compiledUnionJoin` is about four times faster than using `compiledUnion` on `Join[a, b]`.

Comment: Thankyou jkuczm for an excellent solution to my problem. I have one further query; I didn't specify this but I need to be able to work with either Real or Complex numbers. I tried wrapping in `compiledUnionJoin[domain_] := compiledUnionJoin[domain] = (*your code with _Real -> _domain, and a choice of Complex/Real modification for the "comparison with tolerance" part*)`, but this runs nearly twice as slowly. I don't understand why that is, shouldn't this just define two separate compiled functions and choose one as necessary? Do you have a solution for this that doesn't slow the code down?

Comment: @Joe I've added version for complex arguments. Maybe you could edit your question to incorporate you argument types requirements. In my tests version for complex arguments is about 40% slower than version for real arguments when joining `a` and `b` sets, since comparison of complex numbers is more complicated this slowdown is expected.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I edited the question. I wasn't very specific in my comment, sorry; I know that the complex code should be a bit slower, but I was finding even the real code to be slower when wrapped up as I wrote above. As far as I can see this shouldn't change anything but maybe I've misunderstood `f[x_] := f[x] = (*f here*)`
When I run your code I get a bunch of compile errors, but perhaps this is because I'm on Mathematica 8? I will try on a newer version also when I can. `compiledUnionJoin[Real][{{0.1}}, {{0.101}}, 0.1]` for me evaluates to `Sequence[{{0.1}}, {{0.101}}, 0.1]`

Comment: @Joe I've adapted code to version 8. Just two small tweaks were needed in compiled code. `SameQ` is compilable from version 9, so it needed to be changed to `Equal`. `Table` with number as iterator is allowed since version 10.2, in previous versions iterator always needed to be a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Union[a,b]]
```