# Why the "Sum" function becomes extremely slow at a specific size of matrix? How to AVOID it?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

Three methods("Sum", "Total@Table" and "Do") have been used to do the same work. The "Sum" and "Total@Table" function becomes extremely slow at num=250 (This number may depend on Computer's condition. My Laptop is MacBook Pro 2013 Late with 8G DRAM).  I hope to understand the reason and how to **AVOID** it

```
timelist = ConstantArray[0, {3, 20}];
Do[
 num = nn*1 + 239;
 mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, num, 2, 2, 2}];
 timelist[[1, nn]] = 
  Timing[r1 = Sum[mat[[l, 1]] l, {l, 1, num}];][[1]];
 timelist[[2, nn]] = 
  Timing[r2 = Total@Table[mat[[l, 1]] l, {l, 1, num}];][[1]];
 timelist[[3, nn]] = Timing[r3 = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[r2]];
    Do[r3 = r3 + mat[[l, 1]] l, {l, 1, num}];][[1]];
 (*SameQ[r1,r2,r3]*)
 , {nn, 1, 20}]
ListLinePlot[timelist, DataRange -> {240, 260}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Sum", "Total@Table", "Do"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"num", "Seconds"}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image: Timing Results(My laptop is MacBook 13 2013)]

Comment: see [sudden increase in timing when summing over 250 entries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55242/125)

Answer (score 5):

An FYI, too long for a comment, concerning a 4th approach taking advantage of vectorization in the MKL. (The answer to the main question, which is connected to system `Compile` thresholds, may be found at [Sudden increase in timing when summing over 250 entries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55242/Sudden-increase-in-timing-when-summing-over-250-entries), which was pointed out by @kglr.)

```
timelist = ConstantArray[0, {4, 20}];
Do[num = nn*1 + 239;
 mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, num, 2, 2, 2}];
 timelist[[1, nn]] = 
  AbsoluteTiming[r1 = Sum[mat[[l, 1]] l, {l, 1, num}];][[1]];
 timelist[[2, nn]] = 
  AbsoluteTiming[r2 = Total@Table[mat[[l, 1]] l, {l, 1, num}];][[1]];
 timelist[[3, nn]] = 
  AbsoluteTiming[r3 = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[r2]];
    Do[r3 = r3 + mat[[l, 1]] l, {l, 1, num}];][[1]];
 timelist[[4, nn]] = 
  AbsoluteTiming[r4 =  Total[mat[[All, 1]] Range[num]]; ][[1]],
 {nn, 1, 20}]
ListLinePlot[timelist, DataRange -> {240, 260}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Sum", "Total@Table", "Do", "Total@vectorized"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"num", "Seconds"}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

```
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
(*  True  *)
```

Concerning my preference for `AbsoluteTiming`: [Difference between AbsoluteTiming and Timing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14152/difference-between-absolutetiming-and-timing)