# Unexpected optimization with With

Tags: performance-tuning, scoping

I do not understand why the function `With[{y = #}, {y, y, y}] &` maps faster than the function `{#, #, #} &`. The difference is appreciable in my system.

```
Module[{p = RandomInteger[1000, 100], n = 1000000, 
  f = Function[Null, {#, #, #}], 
  g = Function[Null, {#, #, #}, HoldAll]}, { 
  Timing[Do[With[{y = #}, {y, y, y}] & /@ p, {n}]], 
  Timing[Do[{#, #, #} & /@ p, {n}]],
  Timing[Do[f /@ p, {n}]], 
  Timing[Do[g /@ p, {n}]]}]

(*{{9.031250, Null}, {11.078125, Null}, {11.125000, Null}, {11.203125, Null}}*)
```

I thought that the time saving came from `With` having attribute `HoldAll` but the timing of the function `g` above is similar to the other slower functions.

Is there any rule of thumbs to use `With` to speed up the code?

---

The question has been partially answered by Alexey's comment below. Nevertheless, would the following rule be valid (?): Compiled numerical functions that use the input in several places benefit from `With`.

Comment: On my laptop I get `{15.0229, 16.8793, 17.0353, 17.1757}` as timings. The difference is small but really surprising. Probably it is somehow related to [auto-compilation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54996/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: you were right on target! Changing `p = RandomInteger[1000, 100]` to `p = RandomInteger[1000, 50]` results in a drastic increase of the timings `{78.6, 27.6, 27.7, 36.5}`. The function with `With` is now slower as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Alexey's supposition we can indeed find a difference in the compilation of these functions.  I shall compare only two forms as the other cases appear similar.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

f1 = With[{y = #}, {y, y, y}] &;
f2 = {#, #, #} &;

{cf1, cf2} = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}}, # /@ x] & /@ {f1, f2};

CompilePrint /@ {cf1, cf2}
```

Abridged output:

```
1   I2 = Length[ T(I1)0]
2   I5 = I6
3   T(I2)2 = Table[ I2, I5]
4   I4 = I7
5   goto 9
6   I8 = GetElement[ T(I1)0, I4]
7   T(I1)3 = {I8, I8, I8}
8   Element[ T(I2)2, I5] = T(I1)3
9   if[ ++ I4 <= I2] goto 6
10  Return

1   I2 = Length[ T(I1)0]
2   I6 = I8
3   T(I2)2 = Table[ I2, I6]
4   I4 = I9
5   goto 11
6   I5 = GetElement[ T(I1)0, I4]
7   I7 = GetElement[ T(I1)0, I4]
8   I10 = GetElement[ T(I1)0, I4]
9   T(I1)3 = {I5, I7, I10}
10  Element[ T(I2)2, I6] = T(I1)3
11  if[ ++ I4 <= I2] goto 6
12  Return
```

So it seems that `With` does make it down into the compiled function in the form of a single GetElement operation rather than three.  What surprises me is that this is not already the way that a Function compiles.

Comment: Would you care to speculate on the reason for the lack of optimization? Is there a way for a parameter to change its value each time it is evaluated in a compiled function? I can think of an example using a function with `Hold` attributes, but I fail to devise an example with a compiled function (which implies numerical parameters AFAIK).

Comment: @Hector as I said it surprises me.  I cannot off-hand think of a reason for `{#, #, #} &` not to compile the same as `With[{y = #}, {y, y, y}] &` since as I believe you correctly note the argument must be numeric.  Without your question (thanks) I would have assumed that any `Function` compilation would start by defining variables e.g. `I8 = GetElement[ T(I1)0, I4]` and then referencing them, e.g. `{I8, I8, I8}`, rather than repeated `GetElement` operations.

Comment: `f3 = {##, ##, ##} &;` does compile the expected way (to the same `CompiledFunction` as `f1`).

Comment: @Karsten Very interesting.  I would not have anticipated that.  Does this make sense to you?

Comment: The reason I tried that `f3` was, that `#` is `Slot[1]`, which is kind of like `[[1]]` but for a `Sequence` instead of a `List`. Nevertheless such a behavior is neither optimal nor expected, especially when you write `f2` as `f2 = Function[x, {x, x, x}];`.