# Help with weird behaviour of Map[Take... on large lists

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Lets say I create a giant list:

```
tmp=RandomReal[{1,10},600000000];
```

Now I want to take 10 random sublists of length 150000:

```
rand = RandomInteger[{1, 600000000 - 149999}, 10];
First@AbsoluteTiming@Map[Take[tmp, {#, # + 149999}] &, rand]
(*0.007*)
```

this works fine and is speedy. However if I want to extract a 100 sublists of 150000 I get:

```
rand = RandomInteger[{1, 600000000 - 149999}, 100];
First@AbsoluteTiming@Map[Take[tmp, {#, # + 149999}] &, rand]
(*87.707*)
```

An increase of several orders of magnitude in time! If I use `Do[]` instead of `Map[]` I can speed it up substantially:

```
foo = Table[{}, 100];
First@AbsoluteTiming@
   Do[foo[[i]]=Take[tmp, {rand[[i]], rand[[i]] + 149999}], {i, 1, 100}]
(*0.05*)
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Max

Comment: `Map` is trying to compile your `tmp`. [Why is there a huge performance gap using Map with more than 100 List entries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54994/5478)

Comment: Any reason not using this `RandomReal[{1, 10}, {100, 150000}];`